# implicit expansion in python?

Tags: python, numpy

```
m = np.random.randint(4,size=(4,4,4))
```

Let's say I want to create separate arrays for each integer like this

```
mm=[]
mm.append((m==1).astype(int))
mm.append((m==2).astype(int))
mm.append((m==3).astype(int))
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this without having to explicitly define `m==1`, etc. Is it possible to implement an implicit expansion approach in python as easily as it is in Matlab for multidimensional arrays as shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388802/split-matrix-into-separate-binary-matrices-based-on-integer-value-matlab)?

Comment: MATLAB has finally added broadcasting!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To have a ndim-array as the output, leveraging `broadcasting` -

```
mm = m == np.arange(1,4)[:,None,None,None]
```

Note that we are using `None` which is an alias for [`np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) to extend dimensions for the range array so that with the equality comparison we are effectively doing elementwise comparison against all elements in `m` against all in the range-array. This is needed so that [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) is affected.

For a generic case of comparing a n-dim array `m` against an array of values, say : `ar = np.array([1,2,3])`, we would use a reshaping to bring on the same dimension-extending effect, like so -

```
mm = m == ar.reshape((-1,)+(1,)*m.ndim)
```

Or, use the built-in `np.equal.outer`, as we are essentially doing outer equality comparison -

```
mm = np.equal.outer(ar,m)
```

Finally, convert to `int` for int dtype array : `mm.astype(int)`.

Comment: nice broadcasting! +1

Comment: @Divakar: Thanks, this works great. However I don't understand why it works... What is the meaning of `[:,None,None,None]` in this case?

Comment: @HappyPy Added few comments for clarification.

Comment: @Divakar: Many thanks for the additional edits and explanation.

Comment: The key to broadcasting is that dimensions can be added automatically at the start, but have to be explicit at the end.  That's what the `None`s are doing.

Answer (score 3):

```
mm = [(m==n).astype(int) for n in np.unique(m)]
```

will give you the `masks` on `m` for all *unique* values in `m`